# sonyericsson xperia x10 del key

Tags: java, android, keylistener

I open virtual keyboard and get pressed key in my 2d application. but virtual keyboard doesn't give any response when I press `DEL` key on virtual keyboard.

How can I know when user press DEL key or can I add global keylistener to system?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is create your own edit based on EditText widget:

```
public class CustomEditText extends EditText {
    public CustomEditText(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public CustomEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public CustomEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }
}
```

Then, override the method OnKeyPreIme

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyPreIme(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DEL) {
        // Do something
    }
    return super.onKeyPreIme(keyCode, event);
}
```

Of course, above method works if you have an EditText for which on-screen keyboard is opened(but you can create one with the size of 0 dip, anyway)

Comment: I dont use EditText. I just show a my extended basic view. and, I try to implement your code to my view, but it doesnt work. actually, DEL key works other android devices, but only xperia. xperia has 12 keys numpad, not whole qwerty keyboard. problem may be related with this

Comment: And how do you receive pressed key? with onKeyDown?

Comment: yes, onkeydown and onkeyup works fine for other chars. but only DEL key. also, DEL key works fine with other devices. it s strange. actually it may be about numpad system.

Comment: I've just checked this and found a solution(got an x10 here). Simply change the input method(by long-pressing on any edit) to the Android Keyboard(from "Default Input Method" or something like that) - keycodes for Del key will appear. Default input method type for x10 is buggy.